# Not running .htaccess file using php

Tags: .htaccess

Im new to this
I want to write .htaccess file for my project.I wrote this code as im running on my localhost :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://192.168.1.185/location/new/project/rss\.php$   http://192.168.1.185/location/new/project/folder/rss.php
```

I want to redirect `http://192.168.1.185/location/new/project/rss.php` to `http://192.168.1.185/location/new/project/folder/rss.php`

This not working.Is im doing anything wrong? please help me on this thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite rules only take the `path` part of the URL (URI) into consideration ([an excellent article on mod_rewrite](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/)). The rest is ignored.

However, if your redirection needs to be permanent its much better to avoid `mod_rewrite` and simply use [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

```
Redirect /vroomrelocation/new/vroomvroom/rss.php /vroomrelocation/new/vroomvroom/yash/rss.php
```

Comment: Yes. You could also specify what response code will be sent to the requester (301, 302, etc.) which is explained on the link I provided (the one regarding Redirect).

Comment: For the URLs you specified in your comment it would be enough to simply use `Redirect /yash/rss.php /rss.php` however do take note that this is the opposite situation from the one you specified in the question. I mean here is `/yash/rss.php` redirected to `rss.php` but in your question you asked how to redirect `/rss.php` to `/yash/rss.php`. Whatever redirection you want the URL on the left in the `Redirect` directive is the URL you want to redirect and the one on the right is the URL to which you want to redirect the first URL.

Comment: i want to redirect to `rss.php` from `/yash/rss.php`. can i use `http://` in front of them ?

Comment: No you can't because the first URL needs to be a path (begins with `/`) since its always considered to be part of the site itself. The second URL can contain `http://` but there is no need to here because its also on the same web site (domain). You would only need to use it if you were to use external redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in htaccess myself, but this should work:

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect rss.php http://192.168.1.185/vroomrelocation/new/vroomvroom/yash/rss.php
```

And put it in the rss.php directory, not the base directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the `.htaccess` file inside the root of your website, you should write:

```
Redirect /vroomrelocation/new/vroomvroom/rss.php /vroomrelocation/new/vroomvroom/yash/rss.php
```

I recommend to put the file inside `/vroomrelocation/new/vroomvroom/` and write:

```
Redirect rss.php yash/rss.php
```